# pandas dataframe manipulation pivot/groupby/reshape

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to count non zero values for variables for each geography, Any help is highly appreciated.

**input dataframe**

[image]

**desired dataframe**

[image]

**Text format input dataframe**

```
    Geography   A   B   C
0   Europe  0   1.5 3.2
1   Europe  1   1.6 2.0
2   Europe  2   1.6 0.0
3   Europe  1   1.6 0.0
4   Asia    1   1.6 0.0
5   Asia    1   1.6 0.0
6   America 0   1.6 1.0
7   America 1   1.6 1.0
8   America 1   1.6 1.0
```

**Desired Output**

```
    Geography   Variables   Count
0   Europe  A   3
1   Europe  B   4
2   Europe  C   2
3   Asia    A   2
4   Asia    B   2
5   Asia    C   0
6   America A   2
7   America B   3
8   America C   3
```

Comment: Please **always** include your data as text.

Comment: Also your attempt to solve it.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `groupby`:

```
(df.set_index('Geography')
  .ne(0)
  .groupby('Geography', sort=False)
  .sum()
  .stack()
  .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Geography level_1    0
0    Europe       A  3.0
1    Europe       B  4.0
2    Europe       C  2.0
3      Asia       A  2.0
4      Asia       B  2.0
5      Asia       C  0.0
6   America       A  2.0
7   America       B  3.0
8   America       C  3.0
```